# The best way to add assets in elixir phoenix

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

Having spent some time trying to understand the difference between assets and static folders, I am stuck at how I should add my CSS and other files to the assets folder. I added them the way I think should be done but they are not reflecting in static after compilation. I am using webpack to build assets. Please I need help with this?

Comment: How about a simple example with a css file that adds ***one*** style?  Then  post what you expect as well as what you actually get.

Comment: It would help to answer your question if you could provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Saying "I added them the way I think should be done" isn't specific enough for any of us to give you helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Phoenix docs](https://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets):

> Files and directories in **assets/static** will be copied to the
>   destination priv/static/ without changes.
>
> ... ...
>
> The **css and js directories** inside of assets are a convention. Brunch
>   will simply look for all files in assets excluding assets/static and
>   sort all found files by their type.
>
> Processed and concatenated javascript will be put into
>   priv/static/js/app.js, styles will be in priv/static/css/app.css.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This was really helpful. Regards.